# HELP i sent btc from a tor wallet, The recipient hasnt recieved it

Tags: blockchain

I have been on blockchain and seen the transaction into the tor wallet. https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA?filter=5

my torwallet recieve address is     1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA

How do I see what was sent out? As I sent out 2.55 btc, It went to an addy that has not changed so i desperately need to track this down. and see why it hasnt landed

Answer (score 0):

I see that [your wallet](https://blockchain.info/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA) sent out a total of 2.69947368 BTC in [this transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/c737367c4d42f9c7ab93078dad692e55b4a2aea91b73b3638c4c21262cf35651)  on June 2nd, in [block 469404](https://blockchain.info/block-index/1507485), which has now been confirmed 1000+.

Comment: what do you mean 1000+? also the 2.699 was recieved in my wallet, However I remember only sending out 2.55 because of a charge.

Comment: Deposit BTC: 1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA     Balance: BTC 0.018074 i have that left in the wallet... so i recieved 2.699 but could only send out 2.55 due to fee... I dont get how this has happened? and not the address i wanted

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what tor wallet is but you shouldn't be using any web wallets. Just use a SPV wallet and connect through tor. I really like electrum though I haven't used it with tor.
>
> ...
>
> Why take the risk? Just run bitcoin core or electrum over tor:
>
> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1697290.0

I am confused. I like blockchain.info but for some reason I seem to get two completely different results depending on whether I check [this link](https://blockchain.info/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA) or [this link](https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA) but, I suppose that the result of the transaction is the same even if the displayed details are different. I would sure love to hear the reason that they are different though. Either way, your bitcoin, if I have your original address correct, probably went to bitcoin:1PFvdddNKGKrmJcn7pYLeMX186cd1Kfi7e as part of a larger payment.

[image: blockchain.info]
https://blockchain.info/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA

[image: blockchainbdgpzk.onion]
https://blockchainbdgpzk.onion/address/1BMbBKshk9ihrQWMseoDt5bXJvQgQPeRkA

Comment: The second link isn't down, you just have to have your application interface configured.